# Мне нужно сделать что бы при наведении на строку, она меняла цвет. Это нужно сделать без линков и подключения теги <style></style>

Tags: html, css, html5

Как сделать, что бы при наведении на строку, она меняла цвет?

Это нужно сделать без линков и подключения тегов `<style></style>`.

Я пишу так и ничего не происходит

```
<tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#555';" 
onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#333';"></tr>

<tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#555';" 
onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#333';"></tr>
```

Comment: Показанная вами строка отлично работает, цвет меняется, происходит всё что нужно. Если это не так, предоставьте [mcve] и разберитесь, как пользоваться местным редактором вопросов.

Comment: Я ошибся, сори, там <tr>

Comment: Ошиблись не вы, но не суть. В любом случае, если поместить tr в таблицу как положено, то всё отлично работает.

Answer (score 3):

У таблицы предполагается определенная структура: таблица, в ней - строки, в них - ячейки.

```html
<table style="border-collapse: collapse;">
  <tr style="color:#800;border-bottom:1px solid blue;text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.5);"
    onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#555';"
    onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#CCC';">
    <td style="">Мне нужно сделать что бы при наведении на строку, она меняла цвет.</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: <tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#555';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#333';" style="border-top: none;border-bottom-: 1px solid #C1C3D1;color: #252731;font-size: 16px;font-weight: normal;text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(256, 256, 256, 0.1);border-bottom: none">

Comment: @кими чудесно! Это что?

Answer (score 1):

```html
<h1 onmouseover="this.style.color='#555';" onmouseout="this.style.color='#333';">Мне нужно сделать что бы при наведении на строку, она меняла цвет.</h1>
```